# Assign normal float value to c++ cx array

Tags: c++-cx

I defined an array "pointsarray" in c++ cx and I'm trying to assign a normal float value to it:

Definition:

```
bool getPoints(Platform::Array<float>^* pointsarray)
```

Assignment (in the function shown above):

```
pointsarray[0] = points[0].x;
```

Error Message:

> A value of type ""float"" cannot be assigned to an entity of type ""Platform::Array< float, 1U> ^""

Is it possible to get a float value into a cx array (pointer)?

Comment: I don't know c++cx, but you seem to have 3 indirections ( a pointer to a c++cx handle (what ever the `^` is called) and the array itself). You are only resolving one, so if i'm not mistaken the syntax would be something like `(**pointsarray)[0]=points[0].x`. Although, why you would use a pointer to a handle in the first place eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` is unnecessary. You already declared `pointsarray` as a managed reference via `^`. So use this:

```
bool getPoints(const Platform::Array<float>^ pointsarray)
```

Edit: use `const` according to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700131.aspx

> When client code passes an array to a C++ method and the method does not modify it, the method accepts the array as a const Array^.

Comment: Thanks for your tip it helped a lot. It has been solved by changing Platform::Array<float>^* to Platform::WriteOnlyArray<float>^

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please consider accepting my answer then!

Comment: Just removing the " * " doeesn't help because then, the compiler says that in/out arrays are not supported in c++/cx and I should decide.

Comment: I suspect that you should rather use `const Platform::Array<float>^` if `getPoints` only _reads_ the data. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700131.aspx

Comment: In my case I want ta make it as a pointer, which will be assigned values to in my function. I need These values in c# after calling this function. The function just returns true or false.